# How to change the date from DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD using C#

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, datepicker

I am using `DatePicker` to select the Date. So after selecting the date, I should display it through a `MessageBox`. I can able to display it but it is in the format `DD/MM/YYYY`.

And I want to display it in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. So please can anyone help me to do the needful. 
Now I am displaying the date by using the code:

```
string date1 = datepicker.ValueString;
MessageBox.Show(date1);
```

But I can display the current date format and display it as required by using code:

```
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd";

string f = DateTime.Now.ToString(format);
```

So please help me to do the same by using `DatePicker`.

Comment: My issue is solved now. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by using code

```
<toolkit:DatePicker Name="datepicker" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Value="" Background="Transparent" TabNavigation="Cycle" Template="{StaticResource DatePickerControlTemplate1}"/>
```

and in CS file, I added

```
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        string date1 = datepicker.ValueString;
        DateTime datevalue = DateTime.Parse(date1);
        string d = datevalue.ToString(format);
        MessageBox.Show(d);
```

and Lastly I got the required output
and By the way for DatePicker we have to install WPtoolkit Package

Answer (score 1):

Declare this in XAML page (before declaring add the reference file)

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Add this inside ContentPanel

```
<toolkit:DatePicker  Name="datePickerOne"/>
```

Add this in C# page

```
 DateTime dte = new DateTime();
 dte = (DateTime)datePickerOne.Value;
 MessageBox.Show(dte.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```

Now check it.