# Convert various date formats to MM/dd/yyyy in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datetime, windows-phone-8, date-formatting

I am developing an app for Windows Phone. Due to different date formats used across the world, the datepicker in Windows Phone will display date as **dd-MM-yyyy** for users in India and **MM/dd/yyyy** for users in USA, just for an example. So my app crashes as it is set to use the **MM/dd/yyyy** format ONLY for a particular module.

Can you help me with some code snippet as I am unable to find a solution for this?

**Edit:**
My try

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(x.msDate.ToString(),"M/d/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: What is the value of `x.msDate` exactly?

Comment: For example, x.msDate = "24-12-2013";

Comment: How about using a `DateTime` type *everywhere* (with time component == midnight) where you're working with dates? Do you get a string from your date picker? Is that your choice or is this datepicker unable to return `DateTime`?

Comment: Why are you parsing dates at all? A *date picker* should give you the date as a `DateTime`, not as a string.

Comment: I cannot help it. I have it in string and need to use it that way. I know it isn't right.

Comment: i use this snippet for C# to change date format. 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17923591/3244180

Comment: i use this snippet for c#. It is use full 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17923591/3244180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of all the answers did the trick for me. The successful implementation code:

```
    DateTime originalDate,dt;
    String msDate = "24-12-2013";
    String[] format = {"d-M-yyyy","M/d/yyyy"};
    CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    foreach (var frmt in format)
    {
        if(DateTime.TryParseExact(msDate, frmt, enUS, DateTimeStyles.None,out dt))
        {
            originalDate = dt;
            Console.WriteLine(originalDate.ToString());
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the current culture of the machine running the code:

```
MyDateTime.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Or the current culture of the machine running the UI code:

```
MyDateTime.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)
```

Or pass in a specific culture:

```
MyDateTime.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Your example specifies an invariant culture, so it would expect the default DateTime string formatting.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

If you can get your input to pass the DateTime in UTC, that will also make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing string date like you did is dangerous. You should use the DateTime constructor that takes year, month,and day, in that way you will be safe

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2010, 8, 18);
```

Or

So you may use TryParseExact  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: x.msDate is a string coming directly from the database.

Answer (score 1):

As  read from your comments, x.msDate is a string that is stored in a database. If this string can be formatted for different cultures and you need a bit flexibility when parsing, you can use the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method. There is an overload that takes a IFormatProvider as an input. If you want to parse that contains a DateTime in a format that differs from the format of the current culture, you can create a CultureInfo and use its [DateTimeFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property when parsing the DateTime:

```
DateTime dt;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(stringValue, out dt)
{
    if (!DateTime.TryParse(stringValue, new CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)
        throw new ArgumentException("Unable to parse date");
}
// If you reach this line, you were able to parse the DateTime.
```

Also you could create a a list of cultures and try to parse the string with the various culture settings. Once the string was parsed successfully, you return the value:

```
public DateTime ParseString(string value)
{
    CultureInfo[] cultures = {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                              new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                              new CultureInfo("de-DE")};

    foreach(var cult in cultures)
    {
        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(value, cult, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
            return dt;
    }
    throw new ArgumentException(
        string.Format("Unable to parse DateTime for string {0}.", value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you

```
string dateTime= Convert.ToDateTime(datepicker.Value).ToString("M/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```